# How do I bind to just one IP address with VisualSVN Server?

Tags: apache, svn, visualsvn-server

I've installed VisualSVN on my Windows Server 2008.  I have several IP addresses on this server, but I want VisualSVN to only bind to one of them.  By default it binds to all available addresses.  How can I make VisualSVN only handle requests on one IP address?

I tried adding

```
BindAddress xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

to httpd-custom.conf and restarting the service, but that didn't seem to work.

I tried the same with httpd.conf, and it didn't work either.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't do anything except point you to the apache documentation at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/bind.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To clarify, the method for binding VisualSVN to explicitly defined IP addresses is:

1. Load the **VisualSVN Server Manager** MMC snap-in
2. In the left pane, right-click the **VisualSVN Server** item and choose **Properties** from the context menu
3. Click the **Network** tab
4. In the **Server Binding** group, select the radio button for **These IP addresses**
5. For each IP address you want to specify:Click the **Add...** button
6. Enter the IP address in the text box and click **OK**

Comment: This was new with version 1.6.

Answer (score 1):

I found an easy way!  I just upgraded to VisualSVN 1.6.  Then, in the management console, right-click the VisualSVN Server node, select the Network tab, and enter your IP address(es).  Cool!